# How can I debug network requests from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, url, networking, ios, snoop

I want to check the network requests an app is making from my iPhone. It's on the same WiFi network as my computer (or if it makes things easier, I can set it up to use an ad-hoc network). I don't want to see every packet, just the URLs which my iPhone is requesting. I don't care about the returned data all that much.

A simple solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: well, maybe i got this wrong, but why don't you just NSLog the URL's your app is calling?

Comment: `tcpdump` is great for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to intercept the phone itself you'll need to point it at an http proxy you set up on a computer and watch the requests come through.  Something like http://www.charlesproxy.com/ or there are most likely many free proxies.

Comment: I second that. Charles is an awesome proxy.

Answer (score 2):

1. Connect your computer to the rest
   of your local network via Ethernet.
2. Turn on Internet Sharing from the
   Sharing System Preference to share
   your Ethernet connection via
   AirPort.
3. Set your iPhone to
   connect to the computer as its base
   station.
4. Use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to
   capture and analyze the packets.

Answer (score 2):

I found a really nice repo on github named Wormholy https://github.com/pmusolino/Wormholy it will show every network request on your iphone, you only add it to your pod file and then on your app, you shake your phone and you will see all requests.

- Easy to install
- Transparent on your app usage
- Overview and details of your request

Like so
[Screenshot of wormholy usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jczx.png)