#  `Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError` when I post a image from to rails from an iphone application

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

When I post a image from a iphone application, my rails application raises the exception:

> Paperclip exception : Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError].

My iPhone application posts the image by multipart.

When I upload a image from my web site the rails application does not raise this exception.

Where can I look to see why it does not work? Thank you.

Comment: Are you posting from the iphone using a "multipart" form / request?

Comment: Possibly answered here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033425/paperclip-exception-paperclipadapterregistrynohandlererror

Answer (score 0):

I already have had this error on a nested form and it was because I forgot the set the multipart to true.

Use a tool to log requests sent by your iPhone and then you can see were the request is malformed.

[Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) is perfect for that.

Related topic : [How can I debug network requests from my iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924633/how-can-i-debug-network-requests-from-my-iphone)